# declare label in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a label called "test" in my Index.asp page in my MVC view folder. I want to be able to change the value of it in my controller class. Can someone explain how it can be achieved?
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything else that your controller action should do?

Comment: A *.asp page or a *.aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way, but there are better options depending on what you want to do:

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewData["testValue"] = "new label value";
  return View();
}
```

INDEX VIEW - ACCESS THE VALUE LIKE THIS:

```
<label for="test"><%= ViewData["testValue"] %></label>
```

If you use form view models, you can set the display name in the class, and then use the html helpers to generate your form items, which will automatically create your labels based on what you have set them to be.

Comment: No problem. Robert Koritnik left you a comment about what else your controller needs to do.  It's a good question, as manually setting your label this way is probably not necessary if you follow best practices in ASP.NET MVC.